# Как подготовить картинки под разные экраны

Tags: android, android-assets

Как правильно подготавливать и добавлять в проект картинки под разные экраны (mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, etc..) ?

Например, нарисовал я картинку для ImageButton. Мне ее нужно в фотошопе(к примеру) нарезать самому на расширения под разные экраны ?

Или же можно так:

сохранить картинку в максимальном разрешении, потом `import the Image Asset in Android Studio`, потом правый клик мышкой на <kbd>res</kbd> ⇒ <kbd>New</kbd> ⇒ <kbd>Image Asset</kbd> и тогда картинки сами порежутся и поместятся в нужные папки (drawable-mdpi etc..) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Конечно вы можете использовать инструмент *ImageAsset*, который входит в *Android Studio*, он специально для этого существует и избавляет от нудной рутины, так как сам порежет на нужные для ресурсов разрешения (например иконка  hdpi - 72x72 пикселя), размещает нужные картинки по нужным папкам ( -mdpi, -hdpi, -xhdpi и тд.) , добавляет недостающие папки и пр.

Кроме того, инструмент позволяет легко сделать поля, подложку и некоторые прочие функции, актуальные в такой работе, не метаясь между несколькими приложениями - легко, комфортно и очень быстро.

Так же содержит готовый пак стандартных иконок андроид (Clipart -> <kbd>Choose</kbd>).

Однако инструмент имеет существенное ограничение - он не работает с произвольными размерами - только стандартные квадратные иконки (стандартных размеров в пикселях) для статусбара, самого приложения, панели уведомлений и тд., то есть прямоугольный фон для кастомной кнопки произвольных размеров в пикселях (например 40х120 пикселей) он не сделает под все разрешения экранов. Это очень плохо и тут уже приходится самому по старинке.

В общем, для случаев, когда инструмент справится с задачей (а его задача - подготовка различных иконок стандартных размеров), его не только можно, но и нужно использовать, так как он делает всю "черную" работу прямо в IDE, но применить его можно не для всех типов картинок, к сожалению.

Для подготовки 9-patch изображний из "обычного" в *Android Studio* так же существует встроенный инструмент, которым тоже вполне можно и нужно пользоваться:

- правый клик на *.png* картинке -> *Create 9-patch file...*
- в каталоге `res/drawable/` (или `res/mipimap/` если иконки там) создается копия *.png* картинки с расширением *.9.png*
- двойной клик на файле *image.9.png* открывает редактор.

Остальные картинки (нестандартных размеров) приходится подготавливать сторонними инструментами (например, один из [плагинов для Gimp](http://izvornikod.com/Blog/tabid/82/EntryId/5/GIMP-script-for-creating-Android-icons-at-once.aspx)). Для популярных редакторов изображений существуют плагины, несколько облегчающие эту скучную работу, но с другой стороны никто и не говорил, что быть разработчикм под андроид это праздник ..

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Прекрасно объяснили и дали ответ на все, что меня интересовало!!

Answer (score 1):

ImageAsset всегда под рукой, но иногда удобней пользоваться редактором в браузере. Пример:
https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Answer (score 0):

У Google на сайте [Developers: API Guides](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html) расписан весь процесс разработки от и до.

В частности, про поддержку различных разрешений экранов: [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

В двух словах - для каждого профиля `mdpi, hdpi ...` делаются свои ресурсы (иконки и пр.). За основу берутся размеры `mdpi`. Причем иконки могут растягиваться для кратных профилей, например `xhdpi = 2.0 x mdpi`, довольно хорошо самой системой, т.е. делать иконки под каждый профиль может и не стоит.

Для кнопок (и вообще изображений) есть специальный формат - [Nine-patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch) `.9.png` (`png` с прозрачными зонами, задающими направления растягивания кнопки/изображения).

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ. В целом я понимаю как делаются ресурсы под разные экраны, про mdpi, hdpi(x 1.5) я тоже знаю. Мне как-бы больше интересно как это делают другие разработчики, как делают гуру) Сам я - беру картинку, режу ее на определенные размеры, создаю папки drawable и соответственно раскидываю.