# Как выбираются ресурсы из папок xhdpi, hdpi, mdpi и подобных для конкретного устройства?

Tags: android, android-sdk

В моём приложении есть фон и картинка на нём. По умолчанию у меня в AS есть только папка drawable. Создал xxhdpi, xhdpi, hdpi, mdpi в директории res, раскидал по ним уменьшенные копии картинки и фона.  Я так понял, приложение само должно брать картинку из определённой директории в зависимости от разрешения экрана. Но я не понимаю даже, как и к какой картинке обращаться в коде. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

Comment: У всех копий разного размера должно быть одинаковое имя. Обращаетесь вы по id, сгенерипованому R-классом для  этого имени, система сама выберет, исходя из текущей конфигурации системы, наиболее подходящий размер.

Comment: Метки (теги) нужны для того, чтобы выделить основные моменты ВОПРОСА, по которым другие пользователи быстрее смогут найти решение аналогичной проблемы, а не для демонстрации собственных предпочтений в выборе IDE. Вопрос никак не связан с проблемами при работе IDE Android Studio и этот тег в вопросе не нужен

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для начала вам необходимо ознакомиться с официальным руководством [по поддержке устройств с разными размерами экранов](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/practices/screens_support.html). Там предельно подробно объясняется ВСЕ по этой теме.

Для того, чтобы система использовала определенное изображение для какой-то плотности экрана есть два способа:

1. Ручной.
   Вам необходимо создать в директории */res* проекта папки */drawable* с квалификаторами нужной плотности, например для разрешения HDPI, указать соответственно квалификатор -hdpi: */res/drawable-hdpi* (полный список возможных квалификаторов указан в [таблице](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers)).
   В эту папку поместить изображение для указанной плотности с ТАКИМ ЖЕ ИМЕНЕМ файла, структура папок примет следующий вид:

   ```
   res/drawable/
        image1.png
   res/drawable-hdpi/
        image1.png
   res/drawable-xhdpi/
        image1.png
   ```

При запуске программы на конкретном устройстве, система определит, какая плотность пикселей у этого устройства и будет использовать изображение из папки с соответствующим квалификатором. При отсутствии подходящего квалификатора будет выбран ресурс с наиболее близко подходящим значением плотности или из папки */res/drawable/*, если ничего более лучшего не найдется (никакие квалификаторы плотности не указаны).
При сборке проекта IDE сгенерирует файл ресурсов R, в котором будут указаны ссылки на все ресурсы проекта. Обращаться к вашему изображению из кода следует следующим образом:

```
R.drawable.image1
```

Система сама подберет наиболее подходящий вариант для текущего устройства.

2. Автоматический.
   В IDE Android Studio имеется инструмент для автоматической подготовки изображений под разные плотности экрана.

Кликаете на папке *res/* проекта и следуете: *New -> Image Asset*. Откроется инструмент Asset Studio, в котором вам необходимо:

1. выбрать тип подготавливаемого изображения (иконка для приложения, экшенбара или нотификации).
2. указать файл изображения, из которого следует подготовить набор под нужные плотности (чекбокс Image), либо выбрать из дефолтных изображений (чекбокс Clipart)
3. Указать имя, которое получит ресурс в проекте.
4. Так же вы можете задать паддинги, обрезку и форму подложки (квадрат, круг и тд.)

[image: screen]

Нажав кнопку *Next* мастера, вы перейдете на следующий экран, где необходимо выбрать, какие создавать папки для отдельных плотностей - выделяйте нужные вам папки с помощью левого клика с зажатой кнопкой Ctrl (Shift).
Нажав кнопку *Finish* мастера будут автоматически подготовлены изображения для указанных плотностей, создана необходимая структура папок и в них размещены соответствующие изображения.

Недостаток этого инструмента в том, что нельзя так обработать произвольное изображение. Работает только для указанных типов иконок и создает файлы только соответствующего этим иконкам размера, например для иконки приложения под плотность HDPI будет создано изображение, размером 72х72 пикселей.

Так же смотрите эти ответы по смежным вопросам: [ответ1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/460779/177345) и [ответ2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/453000/177345)

Answer (score 2):

> Создал xxhdpi, xhdpi, hdpi, mdpi в директории res

Во-первых должны быть папки под названием `drawable-hdpi`, `drawable-mdpi` и так далее...

> приложение само должно брать картинку из определённой директории в
>   зависимости от разрешения экрана

Да. Именно для этого и нужны специальные папки для каждого разрешения.

> как и к какой картинке обращаться в коде

Для ресурсов расположенных в папке `res` автоматически генерируется класс `R`. Обращение к данным ресурсам происходит через него.