# Android: Как лучше добавлять и хранить новые иконки?

Tags: android, android-studio

Какой способ добавления иконок в `Android Stutio` считается оптимальным на данный момент?

Слышал, что Google рекомендует переходить на векторные иконки. Нет проблем, только ещё пару вопросов:

- Каким образом их лучше добавлять? Через Vector Accet?
- В какой папке их лучше всего хранить?

Comment: Добавляйте как удобно лично вам, хранятся иконки в папке /drawable

Comment: Нет, так не пойдёт. Я, хотя и новичок, но желающий стать хорошим разработчиком, должен знать, почему делаю именно так, а не другим способом.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Иконки - это просто маленькие картинки, которые лежат в папке *res/drawable/* проекта. То, как они туда попадут, вообще не имеет никакого значения и не сопровождается никаким особым ритуалом.

Для векторных иконок вы можете:

1. через любой файловый менеджер закинуть в папку проекта */res/drawable/* любые заранее подготовленные иконки в формате VectorDrawable
2. Выделить в любом файлом менеджере нужные иконки и в контекстном меню выбрать *Копировать*. Затем в Android Studio выделить папку Drawable и в контекстном меню выбрать *Paste (Вставить)*. Будет предложено диалоговое окно с выбором конкретной папки назначения ( с квалификаторами), в случае векторных иконок требуется папка без квалификаторов обычно.
3. через инструмент *Vector Drawable Imporner* выбрать из предустановленного пака по одной иконке
4. через инструмент *Vector Assets* трансформировать в формат VectorDrawable из формата SVG или PSD собственную иконку или опять же выбрать из заранее установленного пака по одной иконке.

остальные инструменты этой серии используются для растровых изображений и здесь уже инструменты Android Studio [более уместны](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483204/177345), так как позволяют автоматически преобразовать иконки в необходимые разрешения и раскидать по соответствующим папкам.  [Подробнее](http://androidgifts.com/material-design-icons-android-studio-drawable-importer/) про плагин Drawable Importer, который использует Android Studio для импорта иконок.

Как видите, первый способ позволяет добавить сразу множество иконок простым копированием, второй позволяет сравнительно быстро раскидать пак по папкам с квалификаторами, если речь идет о растровых иконках, третий - более наглядный и не требует наличия собственных иконок, но медленный, если требуется больше одной иконки или вовсе непригоден для импорта собственных иконок, четвертый - производит преобразование из SVG (этот тип векторной графики не поддерживается Android), чем собственно и ценен, так же позволяет добавлять собственные иконки по одной.
То, каким именно способом будете добавлять иконки именно вы, целиком зависит от ваших предпочтений, а не опыта разработки.