# Как загрузить файлы в папку res Андроид проекта?

Tags: android-studio

Не выходит загрузить файлы в папку res Андроид проекта (пытаюсь загрузить папку с иконками в mitmap с помощью перетаскивания с рабочего стола в Android Studio). Скриншот прилагается. Если включен режим Android, то файлы не загружаются. А если Project, то загружаются,но не доступны для работы в проекте. В чем может быть дело?[image: скриншот]

Comment: Copy -> Paste попробуйте

Comment: название файлов соответствует критериям?

Comment: Copy-Paste пробовал,это действие просто  копирует мою папку со значками в папку проекта, и она попрежнему остается недосягаемой для проекта. 
Иконки генерировал автоматически, так что имена должны соответствовать.

Comment: Кликните на директорию `res` / `new` / `Image Asset`. В поле `Name` введите `ic_launcher_round`, затем `Asset Type` сделаейте `Image` укажите путь до картинки на рабочем столе, прокрутите ниже до `Shape` и выберите там `Circle` и студия сама распределит эту картинку с нужными размерами по нужным папкам.

Comment: папки католога *res/* (как например mipmap) одноуровневые и не могут содержать вложенных папок, чтобы они были доступны в проекте, без дополнительных настроек конфигурации gradle. Поместить иконки можно [разными способами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562389/177345) (для вас, видимо, актуален пункт 2). Так же, вложенные в `ConstraintLayout` другие контейнеры (как `LinearLayout`) фактически плевок на всю идею этого инструмента, на который гугл потратила столько сил, ресурсов и [обучающих материалов](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/constraint-layout/index.html#0)

Comment: ctrl+c  -  ctrl+v

Answer (score -1):

Могу лишь предложить удалить исходную иконку с размером и заменить копи-пастом на такую же подходящий по размеру. Если нужно, отдельно создай директорию и по одной пикче перекинь.