# Конвертировать изображения в Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Есть иконки, которые хочу добавить в студию(размеров xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi).
Нашёл некий [источник](https://pixplicity.com/dp-px-converter/) в котором можно конвертировать изображения.
Вопрос вообщем то в следующем, нужно ли в AS сейчас такое делать или же она как то автоматически преобразует их?

Comment: Установите плагин на Android Studio - Android Drawable Importer - сам все порежет и раскидает по папкам https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7658?pr=

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483204/177345

Answer (score 1):

Нажимаете по папке res правой кнопкой, выбираете New->Image asset, далее указываете картинку. Далее разберетесь