# Замена иконок в Android Studio на свои

Tags: android-studio, icon, drawable

Я хочу в Android Studio в папке drawable поменять значки иконок ic_launcher: ...-hdpi, ...-mdpi, ...-xhdpi, ...-xxhdpi и т.д. Как это сделать?

Comment: Делаете свою иконку, потом New -> Image Asset и [указываете путь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483204/177345) до нее. Все, иконки нужного размера будут размещенный в соответствующих папках. В манифесте указываете эту иконку вместо ic_launcher

Comment: `Ctrl + C` картинку > `Ctrl + V` по папкам.