# Как из Adobe XD добавить картинки в Android Studio

Tags: android, drawable

Когда сделал проект в Android XD,я экспортирую все картинки для Android. В итоге я получаю папочки. Как мне их добавить в папку drawable, чтобы я мог использовать эту картинку. Как я понимаю надо как-то объединить все эти картинки в одну,ибо они для разных разрешений.Но как?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не нужно ничего объединять. Скопируйте все папки в директорию `res`.

Comment: Пришло время узнать о [поддержке разных разрешений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483204/177345) экрана в Android и [системе квалификаторов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/453000/177345) для организации этой поддержки.