# Разработка программы для разрных разрешений экрана

Tags: android

Сделал три страницы с парочкой `EditText`, `TextView`, `Button` и прочее.

Делал для разрешение full HD, а далее запустил данное приложение на меньшем разрешении и все полезло естественно.

Как правильно разрабатывать ПО, что бы подходило для несколько разрешений?

Comment: Возможно вам поможет [ответ по верстке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483756/177345) в Android и заодно [по организации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483204/177345) графических файлов и [системе квалификаторов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/453000/177345) для выбора нужного ресурса

Answer (score 4):

В [документации](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) высветлены основные моменты поддержки разных экранов. Так же можно найти неофициальные переводы этой статьи, но там и так все подробно и доступно описано даже без глубоких знаний английкого языка.

Из личного опыта для максимально простой разметки с поддержкой планшетов, фаблетов и телефонов лучше всего вести все размерности через `/res/values/dimen.xml`. При необходимости вам нужно будет создать папку под соответственное разрешение и просто изменить значения. Например у Вас есть кнопка 40х40dp. На телефоне со средним разрешением экрана она будет выглядеть нормально, а на планшете сильно маленькой. Создав папку `values-w820dp` и добавив туда `dimen.xml` вы увеличиваете все значения в 2 раза и кнопка будет выглядеть такой же относительно длинны экрана.