# Под какие размеры экранов верстать, чтобы поддерживать большую часть экранов Android устройств, наиболее используемых сейчас?

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, genymotion

Я новичок в Android разработке. Заканчиваю свое первое большое приложение, но проблема в том, что на данный момент приложение отображается корректно только на одном типе размерности экранов. Приложение писалось и тестировалось только на одном устройстве.

Такой вопрос, нужно верстать под каждую плотность экранов `mdpi` `hdpi` `xhdpi` `xxhdpi` `xxxhdpi`?
Приложение будет поддерживать только портретную ориентацию и должно работать только на смартфонах (до 7 дюймов примерно), на планшетах нет.   Как лучше сделать? Как быть с картинками?

Знаю что их обязательно нужно масштабировать самому. Например у меня есть большая картинка `700*1500 px`.

К сожалению, нет возможности тестировать на различных физических устройствах, возможно ли все это сделать в `Genymotion`. На каких устройствах тестировать в эмуляторе. Есть вероятность, что что-то в приложении будет работать в эмуляторе не так, как бы это было на физическом устройстве.

Поделитесь опытом.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

Comment: Что делать, когда [кто то ответил](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) на ваш вопрос

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Предварительную оценку компоновки на разных экранах можно выполнить [прямо в визуальном редакторе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/451048/177345) Android Studio, но это очень приблизительный вид и окончательные тесты нужно производить на реальных\виртуальных устройствах.

В настоящее время использование альтернативных эмуляторов, вроде Genymotion имеет смысл только если у вас процессор AMD на ОС Windows, в остальных случаях эмулятор [из SDK предпочтительнее](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/612389/177345) в любом случае. так как позволяет создать **любое** устройство для тестов (в ручном режиме создания устройства).

В "родном" эмуляторе вы можете сделать несколько устройств с разными размерами экрана и плотностью пикселей (или выбрать уже существующие прессеты) и тестировать на них разметку. Для данной задачи эмулятора вполне достаточно и на реальном устройстве с такими же характеристиками экрана проблемы будут только в очень специфических случаях, которые можно просто игнорировать (какие то непрофессиональные кастомные прошивки на устройстве). Genymotion так же имеет некоторый набор тестовых устройств и основные типоразмеры он перекрывает, но иногда их недостаточно.

Наиболее актуальные устройства для тестов (и вообще поддержки вашим приложением) вы можете посмотреть на [официальном Dashboard](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html), где указаны проценты использования тех или иных устройств.
Минимальный набор:

- телефон hdpi, xhdpi  на 4", ~5", ~6".
- Планшет на 7" и на 10" (даже если вы на него не рассчитываете специально, приложение должно выглядеть прилично все же, пользователь может запустить его и не планшете).
- ОС - android 4.4, 5.1, 6,0

По дополнительным вопросам в комментариях.

В термин верстка обычно вкладывается значение, что это взаимное расположение виджетов на экране. Так вот, верстка в андроид практикуется адаптивная, то есть одна под множество размеров экранов. Индивидуальные ресурсы с разделением по размеру\плотности экрана используются, в основном, только для графических файлов на экране и связано это с тем, что на масштабирование и обработку единственного растрового изображения тратится существенный ресурс, на слабых устройствах это вполне может кончится падением приложения, например, по OoME, но и ресурсы мощных устройств не стоит разбазаривать понапрасну. Так же при масштабировании может существенно страдать качество изображения (потеря деталей, лесенки, замыливание и тд)

Тема поддержки различных разрешений экранов очень объемная, но неоднократно обсуждаемая на этом ресурсе. Писать все в очередной раз вижу мало смысла, поэтому пройдемся по уже имеющемуся.

Решение о том, [сколько экранов (layout)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483756/177345) требуется верстать в приложении принимается исходя из различий компоновки на экране, а не его размеров.

Графические файлы подбираются исходя [из плотности пикселей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483204/177345) на устройстве, так же [есть альтернативное](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/621991/177345)  (рекомендуемое) решение. О  [подготовке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/460779/177345) в своем приложении графических файлов и [их добавлении](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562389/177345) в проект.

Указанные выше ответы тоже содержат ссылки на другие ответы, их тоже стоит прочитать.

PS:Я указывал ссылки на свои прошлые ответы, так как знаю, о чем там написано и мне их легче найти. Конечно же, другие участники написали тоже много полезных ответов по этой теме и вы можете воспользоваться поиском по ресурсу , чтобы узнать больше

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Расскажите по поводу тестирования в Genymotion не внешнего вида, а именно функционала, покажет ли он реальную работу устройства, т.е. все ли будет работать точно так же на конкретной модели физического устройства с той же версией api, разрешением, плотностью?

Comment: @ВитяМинашкин нет, эмулятор не полностью эмулирует реальное устройство, скорее это референсное поведение для указанных в эмуляторе характеристик. Производитель может существенно изменять прошивку и это может влиять на поведение программы, Особенно этим грешат Xiaomi, HTC и Samsung. Вместо спасибо здесь голосуют - если ответ помог вам, вы можете проголосовать за него, так же вы можете принять ответ, который наиболее полно решил вашу проблему (серые стрелки и галка слева от ответа)

Comment: Хорошо. Вот вам галочка вместо спасибо.

Answer (score 4):

> Такой вопрос, нужно верстать под каждую плотность экранов mdpi hdpi xhdpi xxhdpi xxxhdpi?

Да, надо верстать отдельно. Обычно делается это так:

1. Берется картинка в хорошем качестве (не менее 2k)
2. Масштабируется до нужного размера (приличным тулом типа Corel или Photoshop)
3. Если речь идет об иконках, то можно воспользоваться [Android Asset Studio](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/)

> Приложение будет поддерживать только портретную ориентацию и должно работать только на смартфонах (до 7 дюймов примерно), на планшетах нет. Как лучше сделать? Как быть с картинками?

Поиграйте с флагами в манифесте:

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true|false"
    android:largeScreens="true|false"
    android:normalScreens="true|false"
    android:smallScreens="true|false"
    android:xlargeScreens="true|false" />
```

> К сожалению, нет возможности тестировать на различных физических устройствах, возможно ли все это сделать в Genymotion

Да, GenyMotion идеальный инструмент для этого

> Есть вероятность, что что-то в приложении будет работать в эмуляторе не так, как бы это было на физическом устройстве?

Конечно. Так оно и будет. Тестирование на эмуляторе выявит 90-99% проблем (зависит от качества верстки лейаутов)

> Поделитесь опытом

1. Не применяйте в лейаутах абсолютные единицы в виде `px` - идеально если все сделано в виде `dpi`
2. Не меняйте размеры программно
3. Заказывайте у дизайнеров картинки не в виде JPG/PNG, а в формате Corel или Photoshop - проще потом их масштабировать.

Comment: прямо в Android Studio есть встроенный [Image Asset Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio.html), который нарежет иконки и сразу раскидает по нужным папкам.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Еще вопрос по поводу верстки макетов. В проект нужно добавлять макеты в зависимости от размера экрана (диагональ в дюймах) и от плотности разрешения (точек на дюйм)? Т.е. на каждый размер все нужные плотности? Макетов получится много.