# Поддержка разных экранов (Адаптивность)

Tags: android

Я вот только начала осваивать Android и решила написать небольшое приложение. Почитала несколько статей, но не смогла нормально понять как сделать адаптивное приложение чтобы все иконки и надписи и layoutы одинаково хорошо смотрелись бы на телефонах, планшетах.

Подскажите пожалуйста следующие вещи:

1. Чтобы иконки нормально отображались на всех устройствах какие папки drawable нужно создать и каких размеров должны быть иконки в них?
2. Чтобы все layoutы одинаково смотрелись на всех устройствах что нужно сделать? Т.е. какие папки создать?

Comment: А как на счет Layout-ов?

Comment: Эти вопросы задавались здесь много раз. Простой поиск поможет вам найти ответы. Можете посмотреть [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/628961/177345) (по вашему вопросу вторая часть), где несколько ссылок на ответы: на правила подготовки layout, графических ресурсов и прочее по верстке в Android

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Правильно ли я поняла что из папок drawable исходя из размеров экрана приложение само будет доставать нужные по размеру иконки?

Comment: Если найдёт подходящее, иначе возмёт из основной :)

Comment: Поняла спасибо.

Comment: Как система [выбирает ресурсы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/453000/177345)

Comment: Думаю почитав эти ресурсы, мне многое станет понятно. Очень благодарна

Comment: рекомендую вам найти и прочитать книгу Б.Харди "Android для профессионалов" 2-е издание.  Она хорошо поможет вам в изучении разработки и там вы найдете ответы на 99% своих вопросов

Answer (score 0):

[`ConstraintLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html). Прочитай про этот новый layout, он с версии AS 2.3. 
Там есть отступы от краев экрана и элементов, так же есть возможность закреплять элементы один за другим.

Answer (score -2):

Можно высчитывать размеры в абстрактных еденицах, вычисляемых из ширины и высоты экрана девайса или сделать разные макеты под каждое разрешение.